How to pass a PyList from Pyo3 to a Polars expression
I'm having trouble passing a Pylist to a polars expression.
I'm trying to pass "period_group" to .over(), however running into some errors.
#[pyfunction]
fn data_bleach(pydf: PyDataFrame, period_group: &Bound<'_, PyList>) -> PyResult<PyDataFrame> {

    let df: DataFrame = pydf.into();
        let df_bleached = df
        .lazy()
        .select([
            when(col("*").over([period_group]).count().gt(5))
            .then(col("*").fill_null(median("*").over(["country", "sector"])))
            .otherwise(col("*").fill_null(mean("*").over(["country", "sector"])))

        ])
        .collect().expect("could not collect"); 
    Ok(PyDataFrame(df_bleached))

}

Error
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Expr: From<&pyo3::Bound<'_, PyList>>` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:20:27
    |
20  |             when(col("*").over([period_group]).gt(5))
    |                           ^^^^ the trait `From<&pyo3::Bound<'_, PyList>>` is not implemented for `Expr`, which is required by `&pyo3::Bound<'_, PyList>: Into<Expr>`



I've tried converting the PyList into a Vec but this didn't work either and results in different error on .over(list)
#[pyfunction]
fn data_bleach(pydf: PyDataFrame, period_group:&Bound<'_, PyList>) -> PyResult<PyDataFrame> {
   
    let list: Vec<String> = pyo3::Bound::extract_bound(&period_group).into_iter()
        .map(|item| item.to_string())
        .collect();


    let df: DataFrame = pydf.into();
        let df_bleached = df
        .lazy()
        .select([
            when(col("*").over(list).count().gt(5))
            .then(col("*").fill_null(median("*").over(["country", "sector"])))
            .otherwise(col("*").fill_null(mean("*").over(["country", "sector"])))

        ])
        .collect().expect("could not collect"); 
    Ok(PyDataFrame(df_bleached))

}


Here is the Error with the Vec<String> pyo3::Bound()
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Expr: From<std::string::String>` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:25:27
    |
25  |             when(col("*").over(list).count().gt(5))
    |                           ^^^^ the trait `From<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `Expr`, which is required by `std::string::String: Into<Expr>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <Expr as From<bool>>
              <Expr as From<i8>>
              <Expr as From<i16>>
              <Expr as From<i32>>
              <Expr as From<i64>>
              <Expr as From<u32>>
              <Expr as From<u64>>
              <Expr as From<f32>>
            and 3 others
    = note: required for `std::string::String` to implement `Into<Expr>`
note: required by a bound in `polars_plan::dsl::<impl Expr>::over`
   --> /home/bourbon/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/polars-plan-0.39.1/src/dsl/mod.rs:908:37
    |
908 |     pub fn over<E: AsRef<[IE]>, IE: Into<Expr> + Clone>(self, partition_by: E) -> Self {
    |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `polars_plan::dsl::<impl Expr>::over`


Here is the error with using let list: Vec<String> = period_group.extract_bound::<Vec<String>>().into_iter().map(|c| col(&c)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
error[E0599]: no method named `extract_bound` found for reference `&pyo3::Bound<'_, PyList>` in the current scope
   --> src/lib.rs:16:42
    |
16  | ...ist: Vec<String> = period_group.extract_bound::<Vec<String>>().into_iter().map(|c| col(&c))...
    |                       -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------
    |                       |            |
    |                       |            this is an associated function, not a method
    |                       help: use associated function syntax instead: `pyo3::Bound<'_, PyList>::extract_bound()`
    |
    = note: found the following associated functions; to be used as methods, functions must have a `self` parameter
note: the candidate is defined in the trait `pyo3::FromPyObject`
   --> /home/bourbon/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.21.2/src/conversion.rs:226:5
    |
226 |     fn extract_bound(ob: &Bound<'py, PyAny>) -> PyResult<Self> {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/lib.rs:16:90
   |
16 | ...ng>>().into_iter().map(|c| col(&c)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
   |                            ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: all function arguments must have a statically known size



What is the error with converting to Vec<String>?

Are you using pyo3-polars? https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-plugins-tutorial/arguments/

@ChayimFriedman I updated the above to include the error on Vec using the into_iter()

@jqurious I'm using py03-polars for passing a dataframe . This works as intended, the only problem is with passing a PyList to a polars expression.

You need to use period_group.extract_bound::<Vec<String>>().

Hi @ChayimFriedman
I tried using that but recived an error suggesting to use the py03::Bound. I modified the example above with the full code using the Vec<String> method.
I'm relieving an error on .over(list) where I provided the compiler suggestion above

You need to use period_group.extract_bound::<Vec<String>>().into_iter().map(|c| col(&c)).collect::<Vec<_>>().

Hi @ChayimFriedman When using that method let list: Vec<String> = period_group.extract_bound::<Vec<String>>().into_iter().map(|c| col(&c)).collect::<Vec<_>>(); I get the last error above

Make it Vec::<String>::extract_bound(&period_group).into_iter().map(|c| col(&c)).collect::<Vec<_>>(). And remove the : Vec<String>.
